# How can two Unicorn servers bind to the same Unix socket?

Tags: sockets, nginx, unicorn

This (rather old) [article](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn) seems to suggest that two Unicorn master processes
can bind to the same Unix socket path:

> When the old master receives the QUIT, it starts gracefully shutting down its workers. Once
>   all the workers have finished serving requests, it dies. We now have a fresh version of our
>   app, fully loaded and ready to receive requests, without any downtime: the old and new workers
>   all share the Unix Domain Socket so nginx doesn’t have to even care about the transition.

Reading around, I don't understand how this is possible. From what I understand, to truly have zero
downtime you have to use `SO_REUSEPORT` to let the old and new servers temporarily be bound to the
same socket. But `SO_REUSEPORT` is [not supported on Unix sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23935961).
(I tested this by binding to a Unix socket path that is already in use by another server, and I got
an `EADDRINUSE`.)

So how can the configuration that the article describes be achieved?

- Nginx forwards HTTP requests to a Unix socket.
- Normally a single Unicorn server accepts requests on this socket and handles them (fair enough).
- During redeployment, a new Unicorn server begins to accept requests on this socket and handles them, while the old server is still running (how?)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the second server calls `unlink` on the socket file immediately before calling `bind` with the same socket file, so in fact there is a small window where no process is bound to the socket and a connection would be refused.

Interestingly, if I bind to a socket file and then immediately delete the file, the next connection to the socket actually gets accepted. The second and subsequent connections are refused with `ENOENT` as expected. So maybe the kernel covers for you somewhat while one process is taking control of a socket that was is bound by another process. (This is on Linux BTW.)